# How to add more than one model/collection to the Backbone View?

Tags: backbone.js

When I add collection to the view like this:

```
var View = new MyCollectionView({ collection: new MyCollection() });
```

everything is okey. I can use this collection in `initialize` method (for binding events, for example). But how can I add another one?

I can't do this way:

```
var View = new MyCollectionView({
  collection: new MyCollection(),
  secondCollection: new MySecondCollection()
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName`, `attributes` and `events`.

So, if you create a view like this:

```
new View({collection: c})
```

then Backbone will automatically assign `c` to the view's `this.collection`. But if you create the view like this:

```
new View({collection: c, secondCollection: c2})
```

then inside the View's constructor:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    // this.collection will be 'c' from above
    // options.secondCollection will be 'c2'
}
```

So you can do this:

```
var View = new MyCollectionView({
  collection: new MyCollection(),
  secondCollection: new MySecondCollection()
});
```

provided that your `MyCollectionView` has an `initialize` method that knows to pull the `secondCollection` out of its `options` argument.

Open your JavaScript console and have a look at what this does:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        var c1 = options.collection;
        var c2 = options.secondCollection;
        console.log(this.collection);
        console.log(c1);
        console.log(c2);
    }
});
var view = new V({collection: 1, secondCollection: 2});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XyeSD/